# When I run the code then type print for command it only prints the words I added instead of the whole sentence

Tags: arrays, data-structures, stack

Java code for a simple stack implementation using a ListStack class along with a basic main program. This code performs actions like adding words to a sentence and printing the sentence. The undo and redo functionality is also included (Still havent implemented)

````
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListStack<String> undo =new ListStack<>();
        ListStack<String> redo =new ListStack<>();
        String[] sen = new String[100];
        int n = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String s1 = sc.nextLine();
        sen = s1.split(" ");

        while (true) {
            String command = sc.next();
            if (command.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            } else if (command.equals("add")) {
                String addWord = sc.next();
                sen[n] = addWord;
                n++;
                undo.push("delete " + addWord);
            } else if (command.equals("print")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    System.out.print(sen[i] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            
        }
    }
}```



This is the output im getting:

Please enter a sentence: Hello world my
add name
add is
print
name is 

This is what my desired output is
Please enter a sentence: Hello world my
add name
add is
print
Hello world my name is 

note: I have ListStack and ListNode classes instead of using the built in java classes
````